# passing data (json) to another controller in swift 5.2 con Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a Login view that asks for a card and password. I consult an API and if the entered data is correct, it sends me a `JSON` like this. Which return has the button method? How do I send that data to the other view? I occupy `Alamofire 5.0` and have my `Model` class.

```
@IBAction func myButtonIngresarAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    guard let carnet = self.txtCarnet.text else {return}
    guard let contrasena = self.txtPassword.text else {return}
     
    let ingresologinmodel = IngresoLoginModel(usuario: carnet, password: contrasena)
    self.apiCall(IngresoLoginModel: ingresologinmodel){
        
        (result) in
        
        switch result{
        case .success(let json):
            print(json)
            **//This is where I want to send that json with the data to the other view. ******
            
            
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
}

enum ApiErros: Error {
    case custom(message : String)
}

typealias Handler = (Swift.Result<Any?, ApiErros>) -> Void

func apiCall(IngresoLoginModel: IngresoLoginModel, completionHandler: @escaping Handler)
{

  let header: HTTPHeaders = [
      .contentType("application/json")
  ]
  
  AF.request("https://url/xxxx/api/Login", method: .post, parameters: IngresoLoginModel,
             encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: header).response{ response in
              debugPrint(response)
              
              switch response.result{
              case .success(let data):
                  do{
                    
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([LoginModel].self, from: data!)
                    print(json)
  
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200{
                        completionHandler(.success(json))
                
                    }else{
                        completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Por favor verifica tu internet")))
                    }
                  }
                  catch
                  {
                    print(error)
                    completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Problemas")))
                  }
              case .failure(let err):
                  print(err.localizedDescription)
              }
  }

  }
```

**Class model**

```
struct LoginModel: Codable {

    let idEmpleado: Int
    let Nombre: String
    let CodEmpleado: String
    let password: String
    let idPerfil: Int
    let activo: Int
    let Descripcion: String
    let idRegion: Int
    let correo: String

}
```

> This is the json that the Api sends me the data changes them for these example

```
{
"idEmpleado": 1,
"nombre": “test”,
"codEmpleado": “000000”,
"password": “123”,
"idPerfil": 4,
"activo": 1,
"Descripcion": “test”,
"idregion": 1,
"correo": “test@test.com"
```

}

Answer (score 2):

many way like create a variable to save this json in OtherViewController and call, self?.otherViewController.json = json
https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Comment: That is correct I have it clear, but this is not a String, it is a json of what type the variable has to be in the second controller and how I access the values ​​of the json from the second view. I appreciate your answer but I have those doubts.

Comment: @franco00719 convert it json to corresponding model. Or create variable with it type is: Any

Comment: as I convert it to the corresponding model that is what I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: Sorry, so you has convert response to your LoginModel, but when you use it in CompletionHandler, you don't know how to use it ?, is that your problem? @franco00719

Comment: Correct that Login Model I don't know how to send it to the other view controlor and be able to access each property from the second view.

Comment: This because you define : 
typealias Handler = (Swift.Result<Any?, ApiErros>) -> Void
You define this is: Swift.Result<Any?, ApiErros) so when success Xcode will know your json as Any?.
Change your define to this: typealias Handler = (Swift.Result<[LoginModel]?, ApiErros>) -> Void.
But I think you should use generic. Write a generic func for all api for example: 
typealias Handler<T: Codable> = (Swift.Result<[T]?, ApiErros>) -> Void 
func apiCall(IngresoLoginModel: LoginModel, completionHandler: @escaping Handler<LoginModel>)

Comment: Hello I have tried to do what you indicate but I am new to Swift and as much as I have wanted to do it, I can not do it if you can help me based on the code that I have shown

Comment: Simply change your Handler to this:  typealias Handler = (Swift.Result<[LoginModel]?, ApiErros>) -> Void. And now your json will be know as Array of LoginModel Object

Comment: I already made the change as you told me, but how do I send that data to the other view, here is my code.       @IBAction func myButtonIngresarAction(_ sender: Any)

Comment: As my first answer, there are many way to send data to other viewController, if you want to help you more, you need to show more infomation in your case. Now, I don't know what is your otherView, and the relationShip between your loginView and your OtherView

Comment: Hello I am going to put it as an answer since here it does not leave me in comments to put many lines of text.

Comment: I need your current context, show me the relationship of Model and current View, and second view

Answer (score 2):

> use didSet

```
var page = [Datas]() {
    didSet {
         self.myVariable = page[0].date!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

typealias Handler = (Swift.Result <[LoginModel]?, ApiErros>) -> Void

> @IBAction func myButtonIngresarAction(_ sender: Any) {

```
    guard let carnet = self.txtCarnet.text else {return}
    guard let contrasena = self.txtPassword.text else {return}
     
    let ingresologinmodel = IngresoLoginModel(usuario: carnet, password: contrasena)
    self.apiCall(IngresoLoginModel: ingresologinmodel){
        
        (result) in
        
        switch result{
        case .success(let json):
        print(json)
    
        //Here is that I do not know how to send it to the other controller all the json

        let viewControllerB = HomeMenuViewController()
            viewControllerB.datosPersonales = json!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)
            
            
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
}
```

second controller

class HomeMenuViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mylabel: UILabel!

var datosPersonales = [LoginModel]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("***************")
    print(datosPersonales)
    print("***************")
}
```

}